# how to generate the report in to excel in java

Tags: java

How to  generate the report in to excel by java. Is there any link that describing  this topics. I am using spring 3. Please suggest the examples.

Comment: why is your question tagged `javascript`?

Comment: I saw a question as report generate by javasript. I dont know it is generate by using client side code or not thats y I tagged. is there any issue?

Comment: I see, I just didn't see why it was tagged that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely need to use some 3rd party libraries. One such option is [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)  library as illustrated in this post by Lars Vogel.

You can check out the sample [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html)

Disclaimer : I havent used it before but the article seems pretty descriptive. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). It seems to be good enough for Excel file generation (though its Word document generator is not mature enough, by the way). I'm not sure it's very easy but it's quite flexible.

Answer (score 1):

We have many library for generate report. I was working with JasperReport and Apache POI.
I think POI is good choose for you. It's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Jxls is a useful option.  It integrates with Apache POI to allow you to have report templates that your Java code fills in with data.

See http://jxls.sourceforge.net/

I used previous versions, but it looks like it has come quite a ways since then.

Answer (score 0):

I use simreport library. I see it is simple enough to make excel reports in java. It make report based on the report you want to make, so it is very easy to understand and edit, customize. It takes me only 15 minutes to start to make the first one. You try it. it's in http://www.jsimreport.com